# Fields in which every odd-degree polynomial has a zero

Tags: reference-request, field-theory

An interesting fact about the field $\mathbb{R}$ is that it's halfway to being algebraically closed, inasmuch as every univariate odd degree polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ has a zero. This isn't true of every field. For example, the cubic polynomial $x^3+x+1$ has no zeroes over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

> **Question.** I'd like to learn more. Are there any relevant definitions or notions that an interested reader could search to get more information?

Comment: Great question, ***+1*** of course; I've often thought about this myself, which probably why I have no answer(s) . . . yet!

Comment: You may be interested in Real-Closed Fields.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2733154/589